# how to validate Jarray response data schema

Tags: njsonschema

I have a json schema validate function something like following

```
private void ValidateJsonSchema<T>(string jsonData)
    {
        var schema = JsonSchema.FromType<T>();
        var errors = schema.Validate(jsonData);
    }
```

the param jsonData is the content of the response, but there is sometimes it will be an array like following

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "title": "abc"
    },
    {
        "id": "456",
        "title": "def"
    }
]
```

so how can I handle this?

Comment: Hi! I'm not familiar with the language, but I'd google how to "if list, while cycle"

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code and it works:

```
        var schema = JsonSchema.FromType(type);
        var jtoken = JToken.Parse(jsonData);
        if (jtoken.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            schema.Type = JsonObjectType.Array;
        var errors = schema.Validate(jtoken);
```